# Which regression method to use for zero-inflated continuous target variable and binary predictor variable?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, poisson-regression

So, i have two columns -

1. first is **Income** (continous). Almost 96% values of this column is 0's since most entries are not having any income.
2. **campaign_support** (binary - 1 means yes and 0 means no), this column has all values.

there are more than 50k samples in the dataset so the sample size is not an issue.

I want to see the incremental impact of campaign_support on income. Any suggestions on which statistical regression method should I use? I thought of using negative binomial regression but it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why doesn’t zero-inflated negative binomial make sense? Is it because your only predictor is binary?

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome :) Yes, that's mostly it. My predictor is binary therefore i don't think negative binomial regression is applicable. After some research, I think the most apt test here is Mann- whintey U test. My only concern is that the target variable is zero-inflated. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at zero inflated lognormal regression. https://github.com/google/lifetime_value

It can accommodate the high number of zeros and also deals with right tail - which I assume you have as your target is "income".

One regressor can simple be added as a one dimensional feature in the X matrix/tensor.